# Print rows according to matching and non-matching columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following use-case:

Table Employee has 3 columns-
EmpID, OfficeMobile,HomeMobile.

Some employees have given same number for both places. Others have given different.
Output should be 2 columns EmpID & ContactNo

If same numbers for both places 1 row else 2 rows.

| EmpID | OfficeMobile | HomeMobile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 | 789 |

Expected Output:

| EmpID | Contact number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 |
| 2 | 789 |

I could come up with this query which can compare the two contact numbers but I'm not finding a way to generate two rows when the home and mobile numbers are different.

```
select ed.empId, 
case 
    when ed.home_number = ed.mobile_number then ed.home_number
    else (ed.home_number )
end as contact
from employeeDetails as ed;
```

Comment: Postgress or MySQL. They are different beasts. PLease dont SPAM Tags

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @RiggsFolly -- that makes no sense -- of course there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL

```
SELECT ed.empId, ed.home_number as contact
FROM employeeDetails ed

UNION ALL

SELECT ed.empId, ed.mobile_number as contact
FROM employeeDetails ed
WHERE ed.home_number <> ed.mobile_number
```

Comment: I figured you were going to go there :) I should have added, with a single query

Comment: @RiggsFolly -- I see what you mean --technically I think that a UNION ALL makes it 1 query but I could also do it with a LATERAL JOIN

Comment: @Hogan This still doesn't print 2 rows for unmatching numbers. Like, in the example, for the EmpId - 2, this returns only one row with mobile number. 
Any idea how can that be achieved? 

Taking the reference of your answer, should I put another UNION with home_number? Something like this... 

`UNION ALL 
SELECT ed.empId, ed.home_number as contact
FROM employeeDetails ed
WHERE ed.home_number <> ed.mobile_number
`

Comment: @shubh586 -- you are right -- see edit